# Case statement with multiple whens...not working!

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

This is a simplified version of what I'm doing, but I can't get anything to work. The statement gives me an error without the comma after 'ERR'. I want the column to be 'Month' and I tohught this would work but I'm having a ton of trouble. Thanks for your help!

```
   select 
 a.POL_PRI_RSK_ST_CD, a.MASTER_COMPANY_NBR,

case

when a.char046 is NULL then 'ERR'

when a.char046 > '010' then '11+'

else a.char046 end as Policy_Years,

a.Last7Days, a.Last30Days, a.Last90Days

from reporting a inner join

Repository b 

on a.RECORD_ID = b.RECORD_ID

where a.POL_OGN_EFF_DT >= '2008-11-01'

group by

a.POL_PRI_RSK_ST_CD, a.MASTER_COMPANY_NBR, 

case

when a.char046 is NULL then 'ERR'

when a.char046 > '010' then '11+'

else a.char046 end as Policy_Years,

a.Last7Days, a.Last30Days, a.Last90Days
```

Comment: Which error do you get after removing the comma?

Comment: END AS MONTH gives me: Incorrect syntax near ','.

After removing the comma I get: The multi-part identifier "day" could not be bound.

Comment: @Daniel: This error has nothing to do with your CASE statement -- there is something wrong with your "day" clause. Show us the complete SQL statment, and we can work on fixing that.

Comment: *The multi-part identifier "day" could not be bound.* you need to tell the query which table "day" comes from.  put the proper table name or alias in front of it: **a.Day, a.year,**...

Comment: @Heinzi thanks, here you go:

insert into R2
select 
 a.day, a.year, a.time,
 case
 when a.char046 is NULL then 'ERR'
 when a.char046 > '010' then '11+'
 else a.char046 end as B2,
 a.minute
from R1

This gives me the bound error. With the comma after 'ERR' i get Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: You write `a.day`, but your source table is called `R1`. You need to tell SQL Server what `a` is. If you want `a` to be an alias for your table `R1`, you need to use the following FROM clause: `FROM R1 a`.

Comment: (BTW: Adding the comma after 'ERR' just adds an additional error that is detected earlier.)

Comment: yah that's added and everything. That part is fine, that's not the problem.

Comment: @Heinzi, ok so I'm now working without the comma but am getting a bound error for each column name

Comment: yes that was already there I just forgot to include in the forum

Comment: Are you sure that there is a field `day` in table `R1`? (Sorry for asking the obvious, but you never know...)

Comment: yah everything is there. Also there is also a group by claue after the from...it has all the same stuff, including another case statement. I use the same syntax as above and it gives me: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

No other error.

Comment: I edited it to show the real statement. incorrect syntax near the second AS

Comment: next time, put the exact error message in the question

Comment: There's no need to use AS in the `GROUP BY` clause. Remove `as Policy_Years`.

Comment: There we go. I thought I was simplifying it by only showing the select statement, but it seems to be running now. Leave a response and I'll checkmark it. Thanks

Comment: (BTW, as long as you are not using any aggregate functions, you might as well drop the whole GROUP BY clause. If you want to avoid duplicates, use `SELECT DISTINCT`.)

Comment: There are aggregates, but I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: This is the outcome of the debugging session in the question comments.*

The error `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.` was caused by `as Policy_Years` in the `GROUP BY` clause. You are not allowed to use `as` within a `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 2):

Try it without commas... example to follow.

```
select  
   case 
      when a.month is NULL then 'ERR'
      when a.month > '011' then '12' 
      else a.month 
   end as Month, 
   a.Last7Days 
from ...
```

Comment: Without commas gives me this message immediately for every day, year, etc.

Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "day" could not be bound.

Comment: Commas are still required to separate the columns of the returned recordset.  You just don't need them within the case statement.

Comment: right, i meant without that one comma after 'ERR'. same error

Comment: Ah, then that's another error.  I would suggest googling the error - i.e. http://aartemiou.blogspot.com/2009/01/multi-part-identifier-could-not-be.html.

Comment: The error you get suggests that the field "day" is not part of the table you're selecting from. Check the schema of the table you're selecting from.

Comment: If a.Month is integer, then cast it to string to match other output values, (or use Str() function)  All cases within a Case must have the same type.  This may be cause of the error

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
     day, year,
case
   when a.month is NULL then 'ERR'
   when a.month > '011' then '12'
   else a.month end as Month,
 a.Last7Days
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing 'AS' after the end of the case.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the commas :

```
select 
     day, year,
     case
       when a.month is NULL then 'ERR'
       when a.month > '011' then '12'
       else a.month 
     end Month,
     a.Last7Days
from [table]
```

Answer (score 0):

Put square brackets around `Day` and `Year`, like this:

```
select a.[Day], a.[Year], ...
```

Comment: it's just an example, day isn't in the actual statement

Comment: Please post the actual statement.

Answer (score 0):

Addressing your new error msg about 'multi-part identifier 'day',

Are `day` and `year` columns in the table ? 
What comes after the From in your query  ? Are you joining multiple tables together in this? Please show the entire query?

ok, based on yr edited question, (You can't use an alias in a Group By)  try this:

```
select a.POL_PRI_RSK_ST_CD, 
  a.MASTER_COMPANY_NBR,
  case when a.char046 is NULL then 'ERR'
       when a.char046 > '010' then '11+'
       else a.char046 end as Policy_Years,
  a.Last7Days, a.Last30Days, a.Last90Days
from reporting a 
   join Repository b 
      on a.RECORD_ID = b.RECORD_ID
where a.POL_OGN_EFF_DT >= '2008-11-01'
group by a.POL_PRI_RSK_ST_CD, 
   a.MASTER_COMPANY_NBR, 
   case when a.char046 is NULL then 'ERR'
        when a.char046 > '010' then '11+'
        else a.char046 end,
   a.Last7Days, a.Last30Days, a.Last90Days
```

but actually, you have no aggregate functions in there at all, just a group by on every expression in the select, so all you need is a Distinct key word , you don;t need the group by at all:

```
select Distinct a.POL_PRI_RSK_ST_CD, 
  a.MASTER_COMPANY_NBR,
  case when a.char046 is NULL then 'ERR'
       when a.char046 > '010' then '11+'
       else a.char046 end as Policy_Years,
  a.Last7Days, a.Last30Days, a.Last90Days
from reporting a 
   join Repository b 
      on a.RECORD_ID = b.RECORD_ID
where a.POL_OGN_EFF_DT >= '2008-11-01'
```

Comment: select 
 a.POL_PRI_RSK_ST_CD as State, a.MASTER_COMPANY_NBR as Original_CO,
         case
 when a.char046 is NULL then 'ERR'
 when a.char046 > '010' then '11+'
 else a.char046 end as Policy_Years,
 a.Last7Days, a.Last30Days, a.Last90Days
from reporting a inner join
Repository b 
on a.RECORD_ID = b.RECORD_ID
where a.POL_OGN_EFF_DT >= '2008-11-01'
group by
 a.POL_PRI_RSK_ST_CD, a.MASTER_COMPANY_NBR, 
 case
 when a.char046 is NULL then 'ERR'
 when a.char046 > '010' then '11+'
 else a.char046 end as Policy_Years,
 a.Last7Days, a.Last30Days, a.Last90Days

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an `AS` alias in the `GROUP BY`.  The expression should match the expression in your SELECT without the alias.